# Remove "Software Update" app from device

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat

I have an [android device](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a350_canvas_knight-5995.php), with which I am facing this spam ad notification issue since quite a few months.

See below screenshot for reference.

[image: Spam ad notification]

Initially I used ignore them and close them by swiping them out of the notification area. But when the frequency of their occurrence got really high, I decided to get rid of the culprit app.

So I googled and found that by pressing for few seconds on the notification we can see the `App Info` menu appear in the notification area as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: Spam ad notification - App Info]

I hoped, that I would be able to uninstall the problematic app, but it wasn't to be. Clicking on `App Info` led me to below shown app.

[image: Spam ad notification - actual app info]

As you can see, there is no option to uninstall the app. I am not sure from where this app came and is it of any use. I just want to remove this app and eventually the ad notification, as sometimes there are some ads for adults only and with my kid playing games on my device its obviously not good.

`Force Stop` doesn't help, neither does clearing data and cache, as the app gets started again after some time. Once you `Force Stop` or clear data and cache, the app appears in the All Apps section instead of running.

[image: All Apps]

But after few minutes or hours it start running again causing the troublesome ad notifications.

I tried searching for removal of this app but my efforts were in vain.

Comment: For the time being you can use a firewall app to stop that app from accessing internet.

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile is rooted, use System App Remove tool from play store & remove the system App.

If mobile is Non-rooted : I don't think that voonik advertise is generated from your software update as it is a pre installed system app, but still you can try to clear cache & force stop and check if advertise is still popping up or not. If it is still popping then check other apps you have downloaded...

Last option should be factory reset..

Comment: I should have mentioned, I've already tried clearing data and cache with `Force Stop`. But it has the same result. After some time the app would be running and would have some data increased > 468KB.

Answer (score 1):

Software update is an essential app for android OS to help you keep up to date with latest version available for your android.

But as you mentioned, you get annoying ads via the app.

I suggest you to not to remove the software update app.

First of all you must be rooted!
Just google to get info.

You should download lucky patcher app.
And patch it to get rid of google ads.

Belive me it works.

Download lucky patcher app- http://lucky-patcher.netbew.com/

Lucky patcher guide- https://www.wattpad.com/125568455-lucky-patcher-tutorial-hack-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 1):

That's actually an adware app in Micromax to fetch and display ADs, just packaged with the name "System Update" to delude us to think it's the app responsible for OTA updates..

I face the same problem in my dad's Micromax Canvas Tab P680.

That app cannot be uninstalled because it's an system app (you need to be rooted to do that as others have said), and *neither* can the app be disabled nor the notifications be disabled from the App Info.

You can use the app "[**Notify Block**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.araneaapps.android.apps.notificationdisable)" to block the notifications from that app (or any other Notification Blocker app)

Or as @Firelord suggested, you can use a firewall app like **[Mobiwol: NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall&hl=en)** to block internet connectivity of that app.